# Migrating a git-svn branch to a git branch

Tags: git, git-svn

My project (which is rather large, at ~2 million lines of code and tens of thousands of commits) is currently switching from git-svn to git. Many users have git-svn branches with history that would be nice to have in the new pure git repository. The basic scenario is like this

The old git-svn repo:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F (master)
```

I have a branch on this repository that has merged master in several times, eg:

```
    G-H---I-J-K (feature)
   /     /
A-B-C-D-E-F (master)
```

I want to move this branch to the new pure-git repository and maintain my history. To make things more complex, the directory structure of the pure-git repository and svn repository is slightly different. Specifically, the base directory structure in this repository has two directories, e.g:

`foo/
bar/`

In the new git repository, `bar/` has been moved to a new repository.

How can I move this branch to the new repository and end up with something like this in the pure-git repo?

```
    G'-H'----I'-J'-K' (feature)
    /       /
A'-B'-C'-D'-E'-F' (master)
```

I thought the following would work:

From the feature branch on the git-svn repo:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch bar" B..HEAD
```

Which should remove all modifications to the foo directory, which is non-existent in the new repo.
Then, add the git-svn repo as a remote for the pure git repo and do this from the pure-git repo:

```
git checkout -b B' feature
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto feature remotes/old_git_svn_repo/master remotes/old_git_svn_repo/feature
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I'm still required to manually resolve all of the merge-conflicts that I've already resolved in my feature branch. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: What does `E'` look like at the moment? Is it a merge commit and if yes, what does it merge if your branch is not in the repo?

Comment: E' is just a regular commit, but I' is a merge between H' and E'. Is there a way I can clarify that in my ASCII diagrams?

Comment: yes, make the line between `H'` and `I'` longer so the line from `E'` to `I'` points in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you did, the first thing you should run is a `filter-branch --index-filter` to fix the tree structure of your branch. But now you need to fix the parent-relationships. Depending on how many merges there have been, there are two options:

- Do it **manually**: have a look at `git help replace`. `git replace` allows you to replace one commit with another. Do this for every merge-base. For example:

  ```
  git replace B B'
  git replace E E'
  ```

  Beware that if you don’t run `filter-branch` on `master..feature`, `B` might allready have a different SHA.

  After this step, you will need to run `filter-branch` again to make the replacements permanent. I would recommend doing the replacements first and then running the `--index-filter`. This way you get it all in one run.
- Do it with a **--parent-filter**. Have a look at the `--parent-filter` argument for `filter-branch`. It will allow you to specify a script to rewrite parent relationships. That script can the use the `git-svn-id:` that should be recorded in every ported commit message to find the matching commits in the new `master`.